# How do I uninstall and completely reset all data from SQL Management Studio?

Tags: ssms

I have tried uninstalling every SQL related program on my computer and the management studio itself, but when I re-install I get the same databases and data.

I just want a fresh install as if I had never touched it. Is this possible?

My Version: 17.9

Comment: Can I have an explanation for the downvote please?

Comment: Irrelevant tags perhaps? (It wasnt me...)

Comment: Management studio is a *client tool*. SQL Server (as it's name kind of implies) is a server. Removing client tools doesn't affect the server at all, which is where the databases "are".

Comment: Oh right, that makes more sense now, I will post back once I have tried removing the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must uninstall the instances that you have on your pc.
[Uninstall an Existing Instance of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-2017)  and [Steps to remove SQL Server 2016 Instance](https://sqlhands.com/2017/04/25/steps-to-remove-sql-server-2016-instance/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.